# Bash Script to setup Github on Rackspace Cloud Sites

Tags: bash, github, rackspace

I'm trying to set up github on a rackspace cloud site. You can't ssh to Rackspace Cloud Sites servers so I'm wondering if I can set up git to link to my github account using a bash script and PHP's exec() or system() commands? Might be a lost cause, any help or advice is appreciated.

I have no idea how to write these kinds of scripts, or even if this is possible, but any assistance would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think this may be all but impossible, at least without using a third-party platform as an intermediary, where a GIT commit triggers an FTP action to upload the changes into Cloud Sites.

It seems Rackspace is happy to leave Cloud Sites as a bog-standard, FTP-accessible hosting offering, and direct all customers who are interested in GIT deployments to their Cloud Servers product.